# Converting string dd.mm.yyyy to date format yyyy-MM-dd using Pyspark

Tags: python, datetime, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column with date in string format: dd.mm.yyyy I want to convert it into date format yyyy-MM-dd using Pyspark, I have tried the following but it's returning null values

```py
df.withColumn("date_col", to_date("string_col", "yyyy-mmm-dd")
```

| string_col | date_col |
| --- | --- |
| 02.11.2008 | null |
| 26.02.2021 | null |

Comment: I modified the question

Comment: How should `"yyyy-mmm-dd"` resemble the format in the input string `26.02.2021`? Try to match it... e.g. with `dd.MM.yyyy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should match the format argument with the right format in your string.
E.g. `df.withColumn("date_col", to_date("string_col", "dd.mm.yyyy")`

Make sure the placement of the day, month and year is correct, as well as the  seperator '.' instead of '-'.

See also the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_date.html)